# Why would you use two(or more) reducers in a MapReduce framework?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Let's say for example you want to count the Names contained in a huge name file. You can easily split the file in to a number of chunks sent it to your mappers and the mappers output to a single reducer which in turn will output a single file containing a  list of the results. That sounds pretty neat !

Now how would two(or more) reducers help this process become faster? As far as I know , all mappers send to every single reducer their own data in order to for it to be reduced and every reducer is going to output its own file with its result. Therefore in a job - with e.g 2 reducers - the data transferred within the system will be multiplied by the number of reducers and the output of all the reducers will be exactly the same(hopefully). Is it worth it for some other instances to have more than one reducers?

It seems as If I am missing something and I would really appreciate a small explanation or some guidance regarding this topic. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you have a confusion about MapReduce. The idea behind to have 2 or more reducers is because you will not want to collapse one machine sending all the information to it. So if you originally were sending 10 records to one reducer, now if you have 2 reducers, the process will be sending 5 records each (best case, it will depends on your hash function)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So If I wanted to use 2 reducers for my example I would just split the data outputted from the mappers using a custom Partitioner and every reducer would get its share(  the equivalent of two systems reducing their own set of data ? ) and their outputs merged in the end ! Therefore this is going to result in a better performance . Is my reasoning correct so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is about how **MapReduce** work. I am going to try to follow the same example you provide in order to have a small explanation to clarify the doubts you have.

The idea behind to have 2 or more reducers is because you will not want to collapse one machine sending all the information to it. So if you originally were sending 10 records to one reducer, now if you have 2 reducers, the process will be sending 5 records each (best case, it will depends on your hash function). Every reducer will get its own share of the data.

Following the same example you provided, let's say you are using combiners so that the mappers will be sending tuples like (I know we can use combiners, it's just an example):

(Joseph, 1)
(George, 1,)
(Andrew, 1)
(Joseph, 1)
(George, 1,)
(Andrew, 1)
(Anibal, 1)
(Mary, 1,)
(Andrew, 1)
(Michael, 1)

If you use 1Reducer, all these records will be sent to the same reducer, so the single output will be:

```
> 10
```

If you are using 2Reducers, in the best case every reducer will get its own share of the data, something like:

```
Reducer1
(Joseph, 1)
(Joseph, 1)
(Andrew, 1)
(Andrew, 1)
(Andrew, 1)

Reducer2
(George, 1,)
(George, 1,)
(Anibal, 1)
(Mary, 1,)
(Michael, 1)
```

For this case you will get 2 outputs, which will be:

```
> 5 
> 5
```

Note that I am assuming that the key will be the **name** found and the output you wanted is just count the number of names in the file.

Answer (score 0):

@dbustosp explained very well.

I would like to add the diagram which will clear your doubt .

[image]

You can see from the above diagram you are achieving parallel processing in the reducer side also.That will give you the high throughput compare to single reducer.